# Contacts on Android: Delete limit exceeded

Tags: contacts, sync

A few days ago I deleted all of my Android contacts (using the "Delete Contacts" app). Not a mistake, I really want to delete them.

From that day, Android always shows a notification "Sync: Too many contacts deletes".
When I click on it, a menu comes:

`Delete limit exceeded

There are 3960 deleted items for contacts, account xxx.xxx@gmail.com. What would you like to do?

- Delete the items.

- Undo the deletes.

- Do nothing for now.`

When I click `Delete the items`, the menu disappears, and nothing seems to happen. The contacts are gone but the notification still sits there. It has been like this for days. What should I do?

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep selecting the option to Delete items anyway. Each time you do, about 50 contacts more will be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Your phone is linked to your Gmail account?  If you log into your account in a web browser and click on "Contacts" in the lower left, does it still show your deleted contacts there?  If you can fix up the list there, it should (?) sync to your phone.

Comment: I have zero contacts in GMail. But "Sync: Too many contacts deletes" always appears on the phone :-(

Answer (score 1):

This happened to my wife's phone too, but I don't remember exactly how she fixed it.  I *think* what she did was disable contact sync, then go to Gmail on the web and delete all the contacts from there, then re-enable contact sync on her phone.

Comment: What worked for me: I deleted all contacts using the Gmail web interface, then rebooted the phone.

Comment: I speaked too fast, the icon reappeared :-/

Answer (score 1):

My phone is rooted.

- I made sure all of my data was correct at `www.google.com/contacts` .
  Then exported the data (`.csv` file) from Google’s web site to my home computer for safe storage.
- I used the app [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) to “Wipe data” for the apps Contacts 4.0.3 and Contacts Storage 4.0.3.
- Waited (approx 1 min) for my phone to re-sync with google and all of the contacts were restored.
- Finally, I went back into Titanium Backup and preformed a full back up for apps Contacts 4.0.3 and Contacts Storage 4.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

After switching to Android 2.2, it works better.
When the icon appears, just click to continue, and after a few times it is done.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as you are now. Here's what I did in the Gmail app:

1. Go to your Gmail account
2. Press menu buton
3. Press settings
4. select your mail id
5. Under data usage
6. Uncheck Sync Gmail.

That should do the trick. It worked for me.